LWC beforeunload preventDefault not preventing page refresh
I'm currently trying to add a confirmation of sorts before the user navigates away from the page. However, when I try to use beforeunload and preventDefault(), it doesn't stop the page from refreshing even though the method is called.
connectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler);
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler);
}

beforeUnloadHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('before unload');
}

When I hit refresh, I can see that 'before unload' gets called in the console, right before the page refreshes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here (I also saw that you can't do this in LWC - I did this previously in visualforce? Not sure if that's the case though)

The Lightning Experience is a Single Page Application (SPA). In a SPA, switching from tab to tab, loading new records, etc, all occur in the same page. The page never unloads, and so the handler is never called. Instead, your best chance of stopping a user from unloading a tab is to disable the ability to close the tab through the disableTabClose method. However, this only works with Console Apps. Alternatively, you could, and probably should, simply store the data in Web Storage so you can recover the data for the user in case they reopen your component.

It seems the handler is called though (Only when I navigate away from Salesforce entirely or refresh the page via browser) I can see the console log called within the handler, though it still refreshes
